# Update an object or create it if does not exist

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

i am trying to do something like canva.com, where you can select images from the sidebar and drop them anywhere in the "div", so you have the capability to drop many images and each image  have its own position.The point is that when i try to use **setState(prevState=>{return [...prevState,{src:...,postitionX:...,positionY:...}]})** This render an img per each pixel while moving the mouse.
[image]

So the problem is when i drag over i have a function that set the position of the mouse, so when the position is changed, useEffect re-render and run the internal function, my goal is to set an object(img) with all the properties of the current img and when i drag over and drop another one, each img has it own position in the drop zone.

```
import React, {useState,useEffect} from 'react'
import Img from "./img-card"
 
const  DropImg=()=>{
  //this state is for getImg, with this i save all the images of the input file (sidebar)
  const [img,setImg]=useState([])
  //this state is for the image shown in the editor
  const[imgDrag,setImgDrag]=useState([])
  //this saves the position of the element currently dragged,then it is passed to the state  that has al the objects that contain all the images with its own data and properties.
  const[position,setPosition]=useState({x:0,y:0})
  //this state is for getting the src of the img that is been dragged in the drag zone
  const [imgSelected,setImageSelected]=useState()

  const getImg=(e)=>{
    let img=e.target.files
    for(let i=0;i<img.length;i++){
      setImg((prevState)=>{return  ( img? [...prevState,URL.createObjectURL(img[i])] : [...prevState]) })
    }
  }

 const dragOver=(e)=>{
    e.preventDefault()
    //clientX and clientY are mouse events that show the position of the pointer
    let xPosition=e.clientX
    let yPosition=e.clientY
    //set the positions to later send the data to the imgDrag that has all the data about the images
    setPosition(()=>{return {["x"]:xPosition,["y"]:yPosition}})
  }
  

  
  useEffect(()=>{
    setImgDrag( (prevState)=>{ return [...prevState, {src:imgSelected, x:position.x, y:position.y,...prevState}]})
  },[position])
 
  function drop(e){
    e.preventDefault();
  }
  
  const dragStart=e=>{
    setImageSelected(e.target.src)
  }

  return (
  <div className="flex bg-gray-400">
    <div className=" bg-gray-800 w-1/4 rem-width-25 px-5 pt-6 h-screen">
      <div className="block">
        <div className="relative bg-teal-500 border rounded  py-12 m-auto text-center  w-11/12   text-white ">
          <input type="file"  id="img" className="absolute top-0  m-auto left-0 cursor-pointer bg-gray-200 border border-gray-300 mb-3 outline-none py-10 px-5 rounded shadow-sm opacity-0" multiple onChange={getImg} />
          Click Here  Or Drop An Image 
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="grid w-full  grid-cols-3 gap-2 mt-10">
        {(img? img.map((src,index)=>{return <Img key={index} id={index} draggable="true" onDragStart={dragStart} src={src}/>}):null)}
      </div>
    </div>
        <div onDrop={drop} onDragOver={dragOver}  className="w-9/12 h-screen relative">
          {imgDrag? imgDrag.map((data)=>{return <Img  src={data.src} style={{width:450,position: 'absolute',top:data.y-400,left:data.x-600}}/>}): null} 
          {img? null:<p id="drop-here" className="text-center">Drop Image Here!</p>}
        </div>
  </div>)
}
export default DropImg
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should fix the duplicate image issues,

```
 useEffect(()=>{
    setImgDrag( (prevState)=>{ return [...prevState.filter(item => item.src !== imgSelected), {src:imgSelected, x:position.x, y:position.y}] })
  },[position])
```